# Finding row in datasheet and replacing it using VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel, replace, find

I am a total newbie when it comes to visual basic and am looking for some help.

Basically I've already written code that takes a data entry sheet and dumps it into a datasheet in the next available free row.

I am now trying to create a separate page in which users can amend details - to get the details to feed into this page I've just simply used VLookups but now I wish to have a macro that will lookup a particular value in a series of rows and then replace that row with the amended row from the new sheet.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated as I am massively struggling.

New Information:

I've put this code together to try to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve - I know this code is not very good and won't achieve it but hoping it goes some way to explaining what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to take "ID" which is located in Sheets("LCH").range("E16"), look for it in Sheets("Data") *It will be located in the first column* then upon finding the value I want to paste all information in SourceRange to the right of it.

Please see code below:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim ID As Range
Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range
Set DestSheet = Sheets("Data")
Set ID = Sheets("LCH").Range("E16")
Set SourceRange = Sheets("LCH").range(E17:E90)
Set DestRange = Sheets("Data").Range("A1:ZZZ500")
DestSheet.Activate
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Find(ID, Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column), xlFormulas, xlWhole, , xlNext)
SourceRange.Copy
DestRange.PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, _
skipblanks:=False, _
Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
End With
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
Application.Goto rng1
Else
MsgBox "10 not found"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post whatever code you have so far so we can give you feedback on it.

Comment: You can use `Find()` to locate a specific value in a particular column (assuming your data has some kind of "identifier" column)

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams - I've edited my post above to try to give a better picture of what I'm trying to achieve, I am such a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim f As Range, IDCell As Range

    Set IDCell = Sheets("LCH").Range("E16")

    Set f = Sheets("Data").Columns(1).Find(IDCell.Value, _
                          LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then

        Sheets("LCH").Range("E17:E90").Copy
        f.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                                    Transpose:=True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Else
        MsgBox "ID '" & IDCell.Value & "' not found on data sheet", vbExclamation
    End If


End Sub
```